# Under Linux boost::interprocess::create_or_open_file change the file type

Tags: c++, linux, file, boost-interprocess

I'm porting a source code to open/read/write a file shared between several process. It works well under windows and as it was mainly using boost::interprocess  (1.44) I didn't expecting too many issue but I found something weird:

```
//pseudo code
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace bipd = boost::interprocess::detail;


loop
    bip::file_handle_t pFile = bipd::create_or_open_file(filename, bip::read_write);
    bipd::acquire_file_lock(pFile);  
    // try to read bytes from pFile with 'read' 
    bipd::truncate_file(pFile, 0);
    bipd::write_file(pFile, (const void*)(textBuffer)), bufLen);
```

When the code run the first time it create the file and write a text. The file mode is ASCII (`ASCII text, with very long lines`) and I can read the text.
But when the loop run for the second times, the file type change to 
`data` and the `textBuffer` is in the file but as binary data !

I inspected `boost/interprocess/details/os_file_functions.hpp` but I didn't find a reason for that behavior.

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution....
It ssems that if you are at the end of the file (file pointer position after the `::read`), the `::ftruncate` function used in the implementation of `boost::interprocess::detail::truncate_file' lead to the incorrect behavior.

to keep the same behavior under Linux and Windows (keep my file type as ASCII Text), I used a simple `::seek(id,0,SEEK_SET)`.

I didn't find that trick in all the page I read !